# How to read from excel and write into excel in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have integrated with Rally which downloads test cases .Every Test case has its own test data in excel spread sheet form.
I am planning to consolidate all test cases excel data into single excel sheet and read the test data from this consolidated excel as part of data driven testing.

So I would like to know how to read from excel and write into excel in protractor.
Hope i am clear .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these node packages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-xlsx

I think the second one would be ideal for you as you need to edit existing excel files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Exceljs to make my test cases data driven.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

Code sample for reading from excel:

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var wrkbook = new Excel.Workbook();
wrkbook.xlsx.readFile('Auto.xlsx').then(function() { 
    var worksheet = wrkbook.getWorksheet('Master');
    worksheet.eachRow(function (Row, rowNumber) {
        console.log("Row " + rowNumber + " = " + JSON.stringify(Row.values));
    });
});
```